# Getting ')' expected. No idea why

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I have a small part of code where I get an error when I try to compile. Any pointers?

The code:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {
                if(fra.linjeList[i].equals(til.linjeList[j])){
                    Linje aktuellLinje=new Linje(linjerMap.get(linjeList[i]));
                    retning=aktuellLinje.stasjonsNummer(startStasjon) - aktuellLinje.stasjonsNummer(sluttStasjon);
                    endeStasjonsNavn=aktuellLinje.endestasjon(retning).stasjonsNavn;
                    System.out.println("Ta T-bane linje " + aktuellLinje.linjeNummer + " fra " + startStasjon + " til " sluttStasjon + " i retning " + endeStasjonsNavn + ". Estimert reisetid: " + tid);



            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the error:

> oblig5.java:132: error: ')' expected
>                                           System.out.println("Ta T-bane linje " + aktuellLinje.linjeNummer + " fra " + startStasjon + " til "
>   sluttStasjon + " i r etning " + endeStasjonsNavn + ". Estimert
>   reisetid: " + tid);
>
> ```
>                                                        ^
> ```

Answer (score 6):

This is the culprit :

```
" til " sluttStasjon
```

Make it

```
" til "  + sluttStasjon
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a `+` before `sluttStasjon` in your print statement

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a plus in

```
" til " sluttStasjon
       ^ HERE
```